# Python: create a dictionary from data in excel

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have data

```
   sign   number    result
Qjobstatus  1   Работаю полный рабочий день
Qjobstatus  2   Работаю неполный рабочий день
Qjobstatus  3   Не работаю
Qcountry    1   Россия
Qcountry    2   Украина
Qcountry    3   Беларусь
Qcountry    4   Азербайджан
Qcountry    5   Армения
Qcountry    6   Грузия
Qcountry    7   Казахстан
Qcountry    8   Кыргызстан
Qcountry    9   Молдова
```

I need to create dictionary where `sign == Qcountry`.
I want to get

```
dict = {1: "Россия",
        2: "Украина",
        3: "Беларусь", ...}
```

I tried

```
if df.sign.contains('Qcountry'):
    dict((ind, el) for (ind, el) in (df.number, df.result))
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
print (df[df['sign']=='Qcountry'].set_index('number')['result'].to_dict())
{1: 'Россия', 
 2: 'Украина', 
 3: 'Беларусь', 
 4: 'Азербайджан', 
 5: 'Армения', 
 6: 'Грузия', 
 7: 'Казахстан', 
 8: 'Кыргызстан', 
 9: 'Молдова'}
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC then you can just call `dict` on the np array:

```
In [284]:
dict(df.loc[df['sign']=='Qcountry','number':].values)

Out[284]:
{1: 'Россия',
 2: 'Украина',
 3: 'Беларусь',
 4: 'Азербайджан',
 5: 'Армения',
 6: 'Грузия',
 7: 'Казахстан',
 8: 'Кыргызстан',
 9: 'Молдова'}
```

Comment: Can you say, why it print me `{1L: u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f', 2L: u'\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430', 3L: u'\u0411\u0435\u043b\u0430\u0440\u0443\u0441\u044c', ...}`?

Comment: Are you running python 2? I'm running python 3 so unicode is being handled correctly

Comment: I think you'll need to decode the strings first, are you able to just use python 3 as this sort of thing just works without all this pain

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a roundabout method but try:

```
df = df[df['sign'] == 'Qcountry']

transposed = df.T.to_dict()
result = {transposed[item]['number']: transposed[item]['result']
       for item in transposed}
```